# How to return an array from Go[lang] to Python using ctypes?

Tags: python, numpy, go, ctypes, ffi

I am trying to write some code that creates an array in GoLang, and returns it to a python script ctypes (and some numpy). What I have got so far doesn't work, and I cannot figure out why... I would appreciate any help!

My Go code goes something like this:

```
func Function(physics_stuff... float64,  N int ) []float64{
    result := make([]float64, N)
    for i:= 0; i< N; i++{
        result[i] =  blah....
    }
    return result;
}
```

and I am currently trying to import this functionality to python using:

```
from ctypes import c_double, cdll, c_int
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./go/library.so")
lib.Function.argtypes = [c_double]*6 + [c_int]

def lovely_python_function(stuff..., N):
    lib.Function.restype = ndpointer(dtype = c_double, shape = (N,))
    return lib.Function(stuff..., N)
```

This python function never returns. Other functions from the same library work just fine, but they all return a single float64 (c_double in python).

Comment: Try `lib.Function.restype = c_double * N` (An array of size N) or `lib.Function.restype = ctypes.POINTER(c_double)  # Outside the function`, and in the function `res = lib.Function(stuff..., N); return [res[i] for i in range(N)]`

Comment: sadly it still doesn't return

Comment: To clarify, the python function does not return even for a small value of `N`?

Comment: Yes, and if I change only the return statement to something else (to the see how long does it take the function to run) everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `restype` is expecting `_ndtpr` type, see:

```
lib.Function.restype = ndpointer(dtype = c_double, shape = (N,))
```

See too in numpy document:

> **def ndpointer(dtype=None, ndim=None, shape=None, flags=None)**
>
> *[others texts]*
>
> Returns
>
> klass : ndpointer type object
>
> > A type object, which is an `_ndtpr` instance containing
> >     dtype, ndim, shape and flags information.
>
> *[others texts]*

In this way `lib.Function.restype` is pointer type which appropriated type in Golang must be `unsafe.Pointer`.

However you want of an slice that need be passed as pointer:

```
func Function(s0, s1, s2 float64, N int) unsafe.Pointer {
    result := make([]float64, N)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        result[i] = (s0 + s1 + s2)
    }
    return unsafe.Pointer(&result)//<-- pointer of result
}
```

This cause a problem in **Rules for passing pointers between Go and C**.

> 2. C code may not keep a copy of a Go pointer after the call returns.
>
> Source: https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/12416-cgo-pointers.md

So you must convert `unsafe.Pointer` to `uintptr` golang type.

```
func Function(s0, s1, s2 float64, N int) uintptr {
    result := make([]float64, N)
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        result[i] = (s0 + s1 + s2)
    }
    return uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&result[0]))//<-- note: result[0]
}
```

In this way you will work fine!

**Note:** The structure of slice in C is represented by `typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;`, but C expect only data, for this is need result only `void *data` (first field, or field[0]).

PoC: https://github.com/ag-studies/stackoverflow-pointers-ref-in-golang

Comment: Got bless you! It works! Thank you! (by the way, I see you haven't pushed the code to the rep, which is a great idea)